# Ray casting in rotating fan configuration produces point cloud with curvature, how to eliminate curvature?

Tags: c++, intersection, point-clouds

I'm attempting to perform an intersection test using ray casting (not sure if correct term so please forgive me if not) and am outputting the intersections as a point cloud, and the point cloud shows curvature (on the Z-axis only, the point cloud is completely flat on the Y axis, and the horizontal axis in this image is the X axis):
[image]

I borrowed concepts from the Scratchapixel site, specifically http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-box-intersection.

Essentially, I am generating 16 rays, all with the same origin vector.  The direction vectors start at +15 degrees on the YZ plane, and continue in increments of -2 degrees down to -15.  I have an axis aligned bounding box that I am testing intersection with.  I use a rotation transform to rotate the 16 rays CCW around the Z axis.  I am performing the intersection test for all 16 rays each 0.1 degrees, and if it returns true, I add the point to the point cloud.

Here's my intersection code:

```
bool test_intersect(Box b, Ray r, Vec3f& intersect_point)
{
    float txmin = 0.0f, txmax = 0.0f, tymin = 0.0f, tymax = 0.0f, tzmin = 0.0f, tzmax = 0.0f;
    float t_min = 0.0f, t_max = 0.0f, t = 0.0f;

    // Determine inverse direction of ray to alleviate 0 = -0 issues
    Vec3f inverse_direction(1 / r.direction.x, 1 / r.direction.y, 1 / r.direction.z);

    // Solving box_min/box_max0 = O + Dt 
    txmin = (b.box_min.x - r.origin.x) * inverse_direction.x;
    txmax = (b.box_max.x - r.origin.x) * inverse_direction.x;
    tymin = (b.box_min.y - r.origin.y) * inverse_direction.y;
    tymax = (b.box_max.y - r.origin.y) * inverse_direction.y;
    tzmin = (b.box_min.z - r.origin.z) * inverse_direction.z;
    tzmax = (b.box_max.z - r.origin.z) * inverse_direction.z;

    // Depending on direction of ray tmin may > tmax, so we may need to swap
    if (txmin > txmax) std::swap(txmin, txmax);
    if (tymin > tymax) std::swap(tymin, tymax);
    if (tzmin > tzmax) std::swap(tzmin, tzmax);

    t_min = txmin;
    t_max = txmax;

    // If t-value of a min is greater than t-value of max,
    // we missed the object in that plane.
    if ((t_min > tymax) || (tymin > t_max))
        return false;

    if (tymin > t_min)
        t_min = tymin;
    if (tymax < t_max)
        t_max = tymax;

    if ((t_min > tzmax) || (tzmin > t_max))
        return false;

    if (tzmin > t_min)
        t_min = tzmin;
    if (tzmax < t_max)
        t_max = tzmax;

    if (t_min > 0)
        t = t_min;
    else
        if (t_max > 0)
            t = t_max;
        else
            return false;

    intersect_point.x = r.origin.x + r.direction.x * t;
    intersect_point.y = r.origin.y + r.direction.y * t;
    intersect_point.z = r.origin.z + r.direction.z * t;

    return true;

}
```

And my rotation:

```
// Rotation around z axis, for rotating array and checking beam intersections
void transform_rotate_z(Vec3f& in_vector, float angle)
{
    float radians = angle * (M_PI / 180);

    float result_x = cos(radians) * in_vector.x + -sin(radians) * in_vector.y;
    float result_y = sin(radians) * in_vector.x + cos(radians) * in_vector.y;
    in_vector.x = result_x;
    in_vector.y = result_y;

}
```

I have racked my brain for quite a while but I can't seem to determine how I can prevent this curvature, I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple.  I'd be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: What software are you using to visualize the point cloud?.

Comment: I'm using Point Cloud Library to write a .PCD file and I've used both pcl_viewer (from Point Cloud Library) on Ubuntu and CloudCompare on Windows to visualize the point cloud.